# Getting Data From Microsoft site

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get the data from the Microsoft website which is an explanation of each enumeration in Excel VBA. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel(enumerations)

I am trying to get each enum's details into the individual worksheet.

I tried the code below.

```vb
Sub MSDNEnumerationList()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, qt As QueryTable, URL As String, ListEnum As Range, R As Long, i As Long

    wsListOfEnums.Activate

    Set ListEnum = wsListOfEnums.Range("C7", Range("C7").End(xlDown))

    For i = 1 To ListEnum.Rows.Count
        wsListOfEnums.Activate
        URL = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel." & LCase(Range("A" & i).Value)
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)

        Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
          Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
          Destination:=Range("A3"))

        With qt
            .Name = wsListOfEnums.Range("C" & R).Value
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingRTF
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .Refresh
        End With

        ws.Name = qt.Name

    Next i

End Sub
```